# Override Jacoco execution on maven child pom

Tags: maven, jacoco

I need to add exclusion for some packages on my pom, but the use of jacoco is set on the parent pom.

Is there a way that I can define only the new execution without overtiring the other configuration?

Is there a way to set the packages I want to exclude in a file??

Comment: could you show related POM fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Define the following in the module you want to modify. It will not effect parent modules. Maven will still resolve artifact Project-B in other child modules of Project-A.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```